# Speed up computation of a sum by summing only over the "noticeably big" terms

Tags: numerical-methods, normal-distribution

Let $c\in\mathbb R$, $$\varphi(x):=e^{-(cx)^2}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R,$$ $d\in\mathbb N$, $D:=[0,1)^d$, $p:D\to(0,1]$, $\sigma:=p^{-\frac1d}$, $$\varphi_x(y):=\frac1{\sigma(x)^d}\varphi\left(\frac{\left\|x-y\right\|}{\sigma(x)}\right)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in D^d\text{ and }y\in\mathbb R^d$$ and $$A_x:=\sum_{i=1}^k:=\sum_{i=1}^k\varphi_{x_i}$$ for $x\in D^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$.

Now, let $\varepsilon\in(0,1]$. We easily see that $$\varphi_x(y)<\varepsilon\Leftrightarrow\left\|x-y\right\|>\frac{\sigma(x)}c\sqrt{-\ln\varepsilon}\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in D\text{ and }y\in\mathbb R^d.\tag1$$

What I want to do is, given $x\in D^k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, numerically compute $A_x(y)$ for any $y\in\mathbb R^d$. By $(1)$, many of the terms in the definition of $A_x(y)$ are neglible small. Since $k$ might be huge, I would like to sum only over the "relevant" terms. Is there anything I can do (save $x$ in a special data structure, for example) to achieve this? I'm only interested in the case $d=2$ if that helps.